# deselecting the listbox value

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm selecting items from one `ListBox` and adding them to second `ListBox` on button click.  The problem is that when I want to deselect the selected items from listbox2, it gives "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.  Below is the code I added behind SELECT button. I have used the same code for deselecting with listbox1 replaced by listbox2 and vice versa.

NOTE: Items in listbbox1 are being retrieved from database and items that got selected in listbox2 will be saved to database

```
List<int> rowIndexes = new List<int>();

foreach (int index in listBox1.SelectedIndices)
{
    DataRowView view = listBox1.Items[index] as DataRowView;
    string id = view["Course_Id"].ToString();
    string name = view["Course_Name"].ToString();
    listBox2.Items.Add(name);
    rowIndexes.Add(index);
}

try
{
    for (int i = rowIndexes.Count; i > 0; i--)
    {
        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndexes[i - 1]);
        dt.AcceptChanges();
    }
}

catch (Exception er)
{
    MessageBox.Show(er.Message);
}
```

Comment: C#? on which line are you getting the error? Is this copied exactly?

Comment: List<int> row Indexes = new List<int>(); contains null .

Comment: The error is on the line `List<int> rowIndexes = new List<int>();`?  That doesn't make any sense - all your doing is creating a new (empty) `List<T>`.

Comment: pardon... the error is in  DataRowView view = listBox1.Items[index] as DataRowView;after inserting consecutive break points at all these staments, i found tht even after the above line is executed, the variable view still contains null. and in its next line, i m assigning the value of view to id..How could this be resolvde?

Answer (score 6):

This is a guess, at best, because the claim that it fails on the first line makes no sense.

My psychic powers tell me that this actually failing at

```
string id = view["Course_Id"].ToString();
```

because view is null. The problem is that

```
DataRowView view = listBox1.Items[index] as DataRowView;
```

is trying to cast the items from a ListBox to DataRowView. This will always return null, unless for some (odd) reason you populated your ListBox.Items with a collection of DataRowView.

*EDIT*

You may be filling listBox1 with DataRowView, but you're filling listBox2 with System.String:

```
string name = view["Course_Name"].ToString();
listBox2.Items.Add(name);
```

Try changing that to

```
//string id = view["Course_Id"].ToString();
//string name = view["Course_Name"].ToString();
listBox2.Items.Add(view);
```

Comment: yeah u r right,, the problem is with view. but it does work fine in moving items from listbox1 to listbox2 then y does error in moving items from listbox2 to listbox1?

Comment: i tried commenting out these two lines and writing listBox2.Items.Add(view); but it gives error tht Items Collections can not be modified when datasource property is set  ???? any help please???

Comment: I take it that the error is on copying back to the original listBox, which was loaded by databinding. It sounds like you're going to need to modify the DataView behind the ListBox.DataSource rather than directly modifying ListBox.Items for that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is copied exactly from your code. This line is incorrect:

```
List<int> row Indexes = new List<int>();
```

its should be:

```
List<int> rowIndexes = new List<int>();
```

Also what is `dt`?

**edit**

If it really is failing on:

```
List<int> rowIndexes = new List<int>();
```

The perhaps you're not:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Or have a reference to `System` in your project references.

Comment: Based on the methods called on `dt` and the variable name, it's probably a `DataTable` :)  Whether or not its in scope at this point is not evident based on the OP's posted code.

Comment: dt is the datatable used for retrieving values from database.

Comment: it is rowIndexes in my code i dont y it is ahowing row Indexes here.

Comment: Do you have a project reference to System and are "using System.Collections.Generic" in your code file?

Comment: yes  i m using generic namespace... any idea what could be the problem here ?